# How does the bible describe heaven

Tags: heaven

I have several questions regarding the main questions.

The reason I'd like to know what the heaven is like, is because I'm wondering why would people rebel against God? I mean I'm thinking heaven as a perfect place.. Including the one who rules it (GOD). Why would anyone rebel against God? How bad can it be? Why would anyone choose any less.

And of course to be able to know if we want to go to heaven or not, we must first know whats in there for us. Like what are the conditions in heaven? What if a person was born with no limbs... and die, will he spend eternity like that? How about what if a person had a face surgery because he was born physically mutilated will the surgery be canceled and spend his life as is? Do we actually have physical images? do we have personalities? do we have like houses or we just stand all together? what are things we do in heaven? besides praise and worship? if we do stop praise and worship does that mean we have a schedule on doing praise and worship?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"*How does the bible describe heaven?*" The fullest description found in the Bible is in [Revelation 21](http://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=Rev&c=21&v=1&t=ESV#top).

Your first question presupposes belief in God, those who don't have faith by definition won't follow God. And of the people that do believe, not all put that belief into practice ([James 2](http://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=Jam&c=2&t=ESV#19), in particular look at verse 19). People do not and cannot choose to go to heaven, it is a blessing given to those who truly believe and follow after God.

What I mean is, if someone was to become a "christian" purely motivated by wanting to go to heaven and not hell, then heaven is nothing more to that person than a carrot-on-a-stick. Being a christian requires far more than simply wishing to go to heaven, it requires belief ([John 3:16-18](http://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=Jhn&c=3&v=16&t=ESV#16), [Romans 10:8-10](http://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=Rom&c=10&v=9&t=ESV#8)), repentance ([Romans 2:3-4](http://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=Rom&c=2&v=3&t=ESV#top), [1 John 1:6-10](http://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=1Jo&c=1&v=6&t=ESV#top)), transformation ([Romans 12:1-2](http://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=Rom&c=12&v=1&t=ESV#top), [Galations 2:16-21](http://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=Gal&c=2&v=20&t=ESV#16)), and faith-produced action ([James 2:14-26](http://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=Jam&c=2&v=14&t=ESV#14)).

In answer to the first portion of your second paragraph, I direct you to
1st Corinthians 15:35-44 (ESV)

> 35) But someone will ask, "How are the dead raised? With what kind of body do they come?" 36) You foolish person! What you sow does not come to life unless it dies. 37) And what you sow is not the body that is to be, but a bare kernel, perhaps of wheat or of some other grain. 38) But God gives it a body as he has chosen, and to each kind of seed its own body. 39) For not all flesh is the same, but there is one kind for humans, another for animals, another for birds, and another for fish. 40) There are heavenly bodies and earthly bodies, but the glory of the heavenly is of one kind, and the glory of the earthly is of another. 41) There is one glory of the sun, and another glory of the moon, and another glory of the stars; for star differs from star in glory. 42) So is it with the resurrection of the dead. What is sown is perishable; what is raised is imperishable. 43) It is sown in dishonor; it is raised in glory. It is sown in weakness; it is raised in power. 44) It is sown a natural body; it is raised a spiritual body. If there is a natural body, there is also a spiritual body.

So to summarize, our physical bodies on earth are entirely different from our spiritual bodies in heaven.

"*do we have like houses or we just stand all together?*" Look at [John 14:1-3](http://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=Jhn&c=14&t=ESV#1)

"*what are things we do in heaven? besides praise and worship? if we do stop praise and worship does that mean we have a schedule on doing praise and worship?*" The short answer is we don't know what we will do in heaven (besides praise and worship and not sinning). You may be interested in the articles [here](http://www.reclaimingthemind.org/blog/2011/02/questions-i-hope-no-one-will-ask-what-will-we-be-doing-in-heaven/) and [here](http://www.gotquestions.org/doing-in-Heaven.html) which both discuss the possibilities (with biblical support of course).

Comment: on revelations there was no description of heaven, only the city of jerusalem coming out from heaven.. correct me if im wrong. If people are not following GOD because of heaven.. is it because of fear of hell? or is it just because his teaching is good? but then there are other good teachings... if its not for the difference in heaven we could follow other teachings...

Comment: No, you are right that Revelation 21 is describing *New Jerusalem*, but many of the descriptions are not about the physical city, but about the state of things. This is (assumedly) applicable to heaven as well. Perhaps I was bad with my wording, heaven is and should be a factor in deciding to become a christian, but it shouldn't be the only one. The Gospel is first and foremost about repentance of and forgiveness for sins, the consequence of that forgiveness is the chance to spend eternity in the presence of God (aka heaven).

Comment: i kinda thought the description of jerusalem in revelation was it was made by man.. i mean why would it be made of gold? gold doesn't mean anything in heaven even then the crystals or gems. those are worthless. its only valuable here on earth. if its rare then its quite more valuable. thats how we value crystals and metals. why is it that it applies to heaven(based on description of jerusalem) as well? actually my main point here is in your last sentence. how is it like to spend eternity in the presence of God.

Comment: The description of Jerusalem was made by John, from visions given to him by God ([Revelation 1:1-2](http://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=Rev&c=1&t=KJV&q=revelation)). As to what its like to spend eternity in the presence of God, try reading [this](http://www.reclaimingthemind.org/blog/2011/02/questions-i-hope-no-one-will-ask-what-will-we-be-doing-in-heaven/). It likely has more and better answers than I do.

Comment: thanks for the reference. is this website the globally accepted christian belief? thanks again for the answers you've given.

Comment: Haha, I'm not even sure there is a globally accepted christian belief outside of the Bible itself. I personally like this particular site because (from what I've seen so far at least) everything they put forward is backed by biblical references, and doesn't have a predominant denominational slant. As with anything outside of the Bible itself, take what you read with a grain of salt, and compare what is said to the Bible before giving it any credit.

Comment: As for your first comment, @FFCoder, "good teachings" don't always mean "true teachings." It's not for the difference of heaven that we should choose to follow the teaching of the bible. If that were so, we'd just choose the best heaven offered from among the various religions. The fact that it is *true* is why we follow it.

Comment: @exxodus7 how to know then which is true, there must be procedure in determining which is true. because what we can observe people who are born in christian countries become christians and same goes for muslim countries. and it doesn't have anything to do with which is true on why they become christians or muslims.. how then can we determine which is true..